# Restangular: getList with object containing embedded array

Tags: angularjs, restangular

In my AngularJS project I'm trying to use the Restangular getList method but it's returning an error because the API response is not directly an array but an object containing an array.

```
{
  "body": [
    // array elements here
  ],
  "paging": null,
  "error": null
}
```

The Restangular error message is:

```
Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
```

Is it possible to tell Restangular that the array it's looking for is inside the `body` property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, see the [Restangular documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setresponseinterceptor-or-setresponseextractor-its-an-alias). You can configure Restangular like so:

```
rc.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation) {
    if (operation === 'getList') {
        var newResponse = response.body;
        newResponse.paging = response.paging;
        newResponse.error = response.error;
        return newResponse;
    }
    return response;
});
```

*Edit*: It seems Restangular's API is now changed, for the better, and that the current method to use is *addResponseInterceptor*. Some adjustments might be needed to the function passed.

Comment: New usage now looks like: `RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {`

Comment: If you want to avoid changing the Restangular config for all your API calls you can create and use a custom config instead, [as described in the docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one)

Answer (score 19):

I think you should use a the customGET from the [Custom Methods](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods)

`Restangular.all("url").customGET(""); // GET /url and handle the response as an Object`

Comment: This is a great solution if only one of your API calls returns an object. Saves you from having to change Restangular's config globally, and also from creating a custom config (in a factory) for an isolated use case.

Comment: This also works if you use solr and get a number of records returned that you need to keep (whereas using an interceptor with getlist you still need to remove it)

Answer (score 6):

as [Collin Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012655/restangular-getlist-with-object-containing-embedded-array#comment34802589_22012970) suggested you can use [addResponseInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor) like this:

```
    app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

        // add a response intereceptor
        RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
          var extractedData;
          // .. to look for getList operations
          if (operation === "getList") {
            // .. and handle the data and meta data
            extractedData = data.body;
            extractedData.error = data.error;
            extractedData.paging = data.paging;
          } else {
            extractedData = data.data;
          }
          return extractedData;
        });

});
```