# Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else in restangular

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, restangular

when i use the following code in my angularJs controller

> ```
> var  baseAccount = Restangular.all('account');
>     $scope.submit = function(){      
>         baseAccount.getList().then(function(accounts) {
>             $scope.datas = accounts ;
>         });
> ```

i get the following error,
 **Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else in restangular**

is there any solution ?

Comment: What does the response from the server look like?

Comment: From server side i returned followind data.

 $names = array("name"=>"ravindra","email"=>"ravindra@gmail.com");
        echo json_encode($names);

Comment: In the browser open up the dev tools and look at the network request. See what the response actually looks like.

Comment: {"name":"ravindra","email":"ravindra@gmail.com"}

Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else this.

Comment: Well that isn't an array. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `getList.` which expects the data from the server to be an array (once it's been parsed into a real JS object). Your response is not an array.

You need to fix the server side code to respond with an array or change the Angular code to request a single resource instead of an array of them:

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.all('account');
$scope.submit = function () {
    baseAccount.get().then(function (account) {
        $scope.data = account; // Only one account
    });
};
```

Comment: yes, i had change the code at server side and works as expected :).
Thanks for the help

Comment: You may also inform Restangular which object property contains the array you're intending to retrieve a list from:   https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case
There's another SO example here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012655/restangular-getlist-with-object-containing-embedded-array