# Restless - "objects" wrapper

Tags: django, flask-restless

I'm working with Restless and [as stated in the documentation](http://restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#testing-the-api), returning Model.objects.all() produces something like this:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "First Post!",
            "author": "daniel",
            "body": "This is the very first post on my shiny-new blog platform...",
            "posted_on": "2014-01-12T15:23:46",
        },
        {
            # More here...
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine. However, I don't want the "objects" wrapper to be here. My front-end code expects an array.
Is there any way of telling Restless not to wrap the array?

Comment: I am not experienced with restless but an [alternative serializer](http://restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#alternative-serialization) might be the way to go.

Comment: I found a way around it: change the behaviour of the front-end instead of the back-end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012655/restangular-getlist-with-object-containing-embedded-array

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding method [`Resource.wrap_list_response()`](http://restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/resources.html#restless.resources.Resource.wrap_list_response). Default implementation just wraps data in a dictionary (within the `objects` key), you can modify this to return data unchanged.